# What is the field DOCKER when we display our Docker machines?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

It's a Google question but I didn't founded the answer so someone here could explain me what is the 7th field (DOCKER) when I do `docker-machine ls`

```
NAME        ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
vbox-vial   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Docker Daemon version.

For further reference, you can visit official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ls/

Comment: Thank you and you know why mine is Unknow despite if I do `docker version` I have this `Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

Comment: Run `docker-machine env` and then `docker-machine regenerate-certs`.

Comment: Thank you for the help !